# functions that deals with endianness only for unsigned value

Tags: c

Maybe I don't find other functions, but all functions that deals with endianness that I find accept only unsigned variable. My question is why (or are there functions that deals with endianness and accept signed variable) ?

List of functions I find : [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/endian) and [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl).

Maybe solution is to use these [macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6961239/7784533) ? What is the difference between macro and above function ?

Comment: Signedness is implementation-defined, and signed integers should not be used to store maps of bits. Still, if you need to do that for a specific reason, why not just cast your `int` to its `unsigned` equivalent first?

Comment: Since you are talking about implementations, it would be valid to bit cast the signed to unsigned (some way of type punning) change the endianness and bit cast it back.

Comment: @underscore_d yes, signedness is implementation-defined, but so is endianness. I think it is OK to assume that OP is referring to a particular implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I byte-swap a signed number in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435665/how-do-i-byte-swap-a-signed-number-in-c)

Comment: @underscore_d simply casting might not be enough, since the sign information can get lost.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya So, by "bit cast", you mean reinterpret via an `unsigned` pointer, rather than casting the value?

Comment: @underscore_d using a pointer would lead to violation of strict aliasing. He can create another unsigned variable (of same size), memcpy the bytes and reverse after changing the endianness.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I think that's incorrect as aliasing rules make an allowance for _"a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object"_. For a non-corresponding type, I would agree. Either way, it's always better to be _too_ paranoid about aliasing, than not paranoid enough. :D

Comment: @underscore_d I agree. I completely missed that point. Either way, I answered the question using `unions`. I am most comfortable with those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since endianness is implementation defined, it is safe to assume that you are talking about an implementation and not C standard. Looking at the links you have sent, I think you refer to Linux and GNU C compiler.

Then under this implementation it is safe to first type pun the `signed int` to `unsigned int`, change the endianness and type pun it back.

Following is one way of doing it

```
union signed_unsigned {
    signed long a;
    unsinged long b;    
} converter;


signed long to_convert = .... //whatever value

converter.a = to_convert;
converter.b = htonl(converted.b);
to_convert = converter.a;
```

You can make this into a macro or a function as you see fit.

As suggested by @underscore_d, the other way to type pun a `signed long` to `unsigned long` (and back) is using pointer cast. That is valid in both C and C++ (although in C++ you should use `reinterpret_cast` rather than C style pointer casts).

You can use the following way to achieve the same.

```
signed long to_convert = .... //whatever value
unsigned long temp = *(unsinged long*)&to_convert;
temp = htonl(temp);
to_convert = *(signed long*)&temp;
```

Comment: In case anyone lands here and wants to use this in C++, note that type-punning via a `union` is only allowed (albeit potentially trapping) in C, not C++, whereas reinterpreting as the corresponding un/signed type will work in both (as it is allowed by the aliasing rules).

Comment: Yes it is on linux with gcc compiler. Thanks for these answers.